# Как сделать такую же анимацию на javascript?

Tags: javascript

В общем, есть такая анимация на css

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
    
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  
  background: tomato;
  animation: move 3s linear forwards;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  top: calc(50% - 60px);
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: calc(50% + 20px);
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

@keyframes move {
  15%, 25% {
    transform: translateX(calc(25vw - 40px));
  }

  40%, 50% {
    transform: translateX(calc(50vw - 40px));
  }

  65%, 75% {
    transform: translateX(calc(75vw - 40px));
  }
  
  90%, 100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(100vw - 40px));
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Как сделать тоже самое на javascript, используя лишь одно значение `p`, которое увеличивается до единицы, а эта самая единица означает конец анимации?

```js
const start_time = now()
const duration = 9

update()

function now() {
  return Date.now() / 1000
}

function translate(el, p) {
  el.style.transform = `translateX(${(innerWidth - 40) * p}px)`
}

function update() {
  const t = now() - start_time
  let p = t / duration

  translate(rect1, p)
  translate(rect2, p)
  translate(rect3, p)

  p < 1 && requestAnimationFrame(update)
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  
  background: tomato;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  top: calc(50% - 60px);
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: calc(50% + 20px);
}
```

```html
<div id=rect1></div>
<div id=rect2></div>
<div id=rect3></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
const
    // Длительность анимации одного элемента
    duration = 9,
    // Все моменты остановок
    stops = [.25, .50, .75, .90],
    // Длительность одной остановки
    stopDuration = .5;

const
    // Преобразуем "stopDuration" так, чтобы он был в интервале от 0 до 1
    stopDuration = stopDuration / duration,
    // Коэффицент ускорения анимации на основе общей длительности остановок
    speed = 1 + 1 / stopDuration * stops.length;

// Количество уже сделаных остановок
let stopsDone = 0;


function update(...elems) {
    if (!elems.length)
        return;

    const t = now() - start_time;
    let p = t / duration;

    // Находим остановку, находящуюся в диапазоне "point - stopDuration / 2" - "point + stopDuration / 2"
    let stop = stops.findIndex(point => p - stopDuration / 2 <= point || p + stopDuration / 2 >= point);
    // Увеличиваем счетчик достигнутых остановок
    if (stopsDone <= stop)
        stopsDone++;

    if (stop !== -1) {
        // Меняем позицию на основе сделаных остановок
        let p = (p - stopsDone * stopDuration) * speed;
        translate(elems[0], p);
    }

    if (p > 1)
        requestAnimationFrame(() => update(...elems))
    // Если анимация закончена, передаем массив со следующим элементом в качестве первого, и так пока элементы не закончатся
    else {
        stopsDone = 0;
        update(...elems.slice(0, -1));
    }
}


update(rect1, rect2, rect3);
```

Comment: Можно живой пример посмотреть? Но по-моему, это не то, что мне нужно. Длительность анимации одного элемента - 3 секунды, а 9 секунд - это время всей анимации + я не могу передавать в `update` никаких значений и `p > 1` железно означает конец анимации

Comment: Короче все элементы должны одновременно обновляться, а не по отдельности.

Comment: @ᅠhᅠ , Тогда массив "elems" можно кинуть за пределы функции, и при окончании анимации просто делать "elems.splice(0, -1)". Если же все элементы должны обновляться одновременно, то достаточно вообще сделать как в изначальном варианте: "translate(rect1, p); translate(rect2, p)...".